# magic packet doesn't work with specified IP address

Tags: wake-on-lan, adsl-router, magic-packet

I'm using Debian with installed `wakeonlan` package.
An old Gigabyte **G41MT-D3** is connected to TP-Link Modem/Router combo with static DHCP IP rule as following: **`192.168.1.110`**
***problem is:***

---

using command `wakeonlan 11:22:33:44:55:66` system send magic packets over broadcast IP with port **`9`** and everything is **fine**!
output:
`Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 11:22:33:44:55:66`
pc starting up immediately after this but using specified IP address it doesn't work!
**e.x**: `wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.110 11:22:33:44:55:66`
**output**: `Sending magic packet to 192.16.1.110:9 with 11:22:33:44:55:66`

note these options:

1. I can connect with RDP by the IP `192.168.1.110`
2. I'm using **DDNS** so RDP port forwarded & I can remote over Internet too.

**I need to know how to fix this, so I can send magic packet over Internet!!**

note that:
I replace `11:22:33:44:55:66` with correct MAC address!

**EDIT:**
ADSL Modem/Router combo model: **`TP-Link TD-W8151N`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the PC is sleeping, the ARP resolution of `192.168.1.110` will fail, so that the packet is not deliverable.

You can either add the MAC address to the static ARP table or broadcast it (from the inside).

Many routers also have a feature to WOL a PC, if a port forward to it is triggered.

Comment: sorry bro I'm still not get the answer, this why your answer still not accepted as answer! but there is a question: if I use my mikrotik & add ip/mac to ARP table, then if I call the ip address router sends packet to corresponding mac?? if not then why add ARP entry?

Comment: Exactly. The router doesn't know, to which **ethernet** address to send the packet for this **IP** address. By adding the ARP entry, you can link these two.

Comment: Super Answer, Thanks! I found some other solutions too, but in case of my question (TP-Link and Other Combo devices) ARP is the best.